# Icinga 2 vs Nagios 4 vs Shinken 2 : is there Performance Benchmarking comparison available?

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring, icinga, check-mk

I am not able to find out any link that displays the benchmarking report for the cores.
We have to monitor 50,000 hosts and 30 services per host

1. per minute host check : icmp
2. per 5 minute service checks : telnet and snmp

We have been using Nagios 3 along with OMD (Check MK) to monitor network of half the size, that is 25,000 hosts and 30 services per host. But now the monitoring infrastructure is coming short on performance and with the new releases in place describing a better scalability we would like to switch on a core that is more scalable in terms of check execution, per cpu core per server.

Comment: The search term that will help find this information is "dimensioning", fwiw

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarks for monitoring environments always differ and numbers won't apply to your requirements. Although there's a rich community for each project on its own where you may ask others to share their experience.

Comparison charts look fancy but I doubt they will help with anything. Which is why we don't have them on icinga.org anymore - if you want to testdrive certain systems, fire up vagrant or docker images and assign them resources.

https://github.com/Icinga/icinga-vagrant

Reading your numbers in relation with Icinga 2 - I would build a distributed cluster system sharing the load inside a HA zone. Start with a lower number and then go further.
Icinga 2's configuration dsl lets you generate configuration using apply rules, loops, functions, etc so bringing up a test config is only a matter of minutes. Take the web2 dev vagrant box for example: https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2/blob/master/.puppet/profiles/icinga2_dev/files/conf.d/test-config.conf#L48

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try Centreon also because it's a really good product. If you use Centreon Engine and Broker you can go up to 100 000 hosts and 500 000 services without any problem !

When I moved from Nagios to Centreon Engine we had about 28 of load (for 500 hosts and 1200 services) on our monitoring servers, now we are at 2 with Centreon Engine on the same server !
If you have any questions you can contact me.